# For loop on XML data in Python returning 4x number of elements expected

Tags: python, xml, for-loop

Using the following code, I load in an XML file that contains email data.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open(xmlFile, "r") as f:
    xml = ElementTree.parse(f)
```

I then initialize all of my variables (subsetted here for brevity):

```
index = []
sender = []
subject = []
date = []
```

And then lastly try to loop through the emails:

```
for node in xml.findall(".//header"): 
  index.append(node.attrib.get('index')) 
  sender.append(node.attrib.get('from')) 
  subject.append(node.attrib.get('subject')) 
  date.append(node.attrib.get('date'))
```

The problem is that when I do that, I get the wrong output. Now, I can't provide the data because it's confidential, but I can give what I believe should be enough to get me looking in the right direction for what's going wrong.

```
In [127]: nodes = xml.findall(".//header")
In [128]: len(nodes)
Out[128]: 12018

In [129]: len(index)
Out[129]: 48072

In [130]: nodes[0].attrib.viewkeys()
Out[130]: dict_keys(['index', 'from', 'read', 'headerLink', 'messageType', 'contentLink', 'state', 'messageId', 'date', 'folder', 'folderId', 'rawLink', 'subject'])

In [130]: index[0:3]
Out[131]: 
['0',
 '(NYTimes.com News Alert) nytdirect@nytimes.com',
 'Breaking News:  At Florida State, Football Eclipses Justice: Records Show Police Often Go Easy on Players']

In [132]: for node in xml.findall(".//header")[0:3]: print(node.attrib.get("index"))
0
1
2
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing? I'm pretty new to Python, but not coding, and I can't see where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run your `for` loop 4 times in the interactive python interpreter? Without reinitializing `index` and other lists ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar No, I didn't. If that were the problem the first three values in `index` would still be [0, 1, 2], but then the whole value set would repeat at position 12018. As you can see above, there are values in `index` that should not be there, which implies it's something other than rerunning the loop without reinitializing.

Comment: is that your exact code? Are you sure you also did not by mistake `append` everything to `index` ?

Comment: Yes, that is my exact code.

Comment: Are you sure you did not do `index = sender = subject = date = []` , for ease?

Comment: Yes, that I did do. Does that cause problems? I checked the length of `index` before running the code again and it came back as 0.

Comment: Yes , it does cause problems .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments  we can see that you did -

```
index = sender = subject = date = []
```

When you do the above, it actually only creates 1 list, and all the names - `index` , `sender` , `subject` , `date` are pointing to that one list. To show that all names are pointing to same list -

```
>>> index = sender = subject = date = []
>>> id(index)
8237464
>>> id(sender)
8237464
>>> id(subject)
8237464
>>> id(date)
8237464
```

And then when you do -

```
for node in xml.findall(".//header"): 
  index.append(node.attrib.get('index')) 
  sender.append(node.attrib.get('from')) 
  subject.append(node.attrib.get('subject')) 
  date.append(node.attrib.get('date'))
```

All the 4 items are added to your single list (which is being referred to by all of the names/variables) . And that is the reason you are seeing all of the data in one list.

You should define each list separately as you gave in your Example and not using the above method -

```
index = []
sender = []
subject = []
date = []
```

Comment: That fixed it. Great explanation as to what's actually happening as well. Helps me learn as well as fixed my problem. Thanks, Anand!